# In how many ways can four integers be selected from $1, 2, 3, \ldots, 35$ so that the difference of any pair of the four numbers is at least $3$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I want to choose $4$ integers from the numbers $1$ to $35$.
Condition: The difference of any pair of the $4$ numbers should be $\geq 3$.

How do I model this problem?

Comment: I suspect you've given some thought to solving this before posting here, and certainly it improves the flow of exposition for all Readers if you included some context:  What did you try?  What motivates interest in such a problem?  Even your solution of a very simplified version of the problem could help to improve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Method 1:**  We reduce the problem to solving an equation in the non-negative integers.

Let the four selected numbers be $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$.  Define
\begin{align*}
x_1 & = a_1\\
x_2 & = a_2 - a_1\\
x_3 & = a_3 - a_2\\
x_4 & = a_4 - a_3\\
x_5 & = 35 - a_4
\end{align*}
Then
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 35 \tag{1}$$
is an equation in the integers in which $x_1 \geq 1$, $x_2, x_3, x_4 \geq 3$, and $x_4 \geq 0$.  If we let 
\begin{align*}
y_1 & = x_1 - 1\\
y_2 & = x_2 - 3\\
y_3 & = x_3 - 3\\
y_4 & = x_4 - 3\\
y_5 & = x_5
\end{align*}
Observe that each $y_k$, $1 \leq k \leq 5$, is a non-negative integer.  If we substitute $y_1 + 1$ for $x_1$, $y_2 + 3$ for $x_2$, $y_3 + 3$ for $x_3$, $y_4 + 3$ for $x_4$, and $y_5$ for $x_5$ in equation 1, we obtain
\begin{align*}
y_1 + 1 + y_2 + 3 + y_3 + 3 + y_4 + 3 + y_5 & = 35\\
y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 + y_5 & = 25 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
A particular solution of equation 2 corresponds to the placement of four addition signs in a row of $25$ ones.  For instance, 
$$+ 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $y_1 = 0$, $y_2 = 5$, $y_3 = 9$, $y_4 = 3$, and $y_5 = 8$.  Hence, the number of solutions of equation 2 in the non-negative integers is 
$$\binom{25 + 4}{4} = \binom{29}{4}$$
since we must select which four of the twenty-nine symbols (twenty-five ones and four addition signs) will be addition signs.

**Method 2:** Line up $29$ balls of different colors in a row, none of which is red.  Select four of these $29$ balls.  Insert two red balls to the immediate right of each of the first three balls you have selected.  Now number the thirty-five balls from left to right.  The numbers on the four balls that you selected correspond to the desired subsequence of $1, 2, 3, \ldots, 35$.  Since we selected these four balls from the $29$ balls that are not red, there are $\binom{29}{4}$ such selections.

**Method 3:**  We represent selections as bit strings of length $35$ in which a $1$ represents a selected number and a $0$ represents a number that has not been selected. We consider cases.

*Case 1*:  The number $35$ is selected.

There must be a $1$ in the final position.  Since any two selected numbers must differ by at least $3$, each of the first three ones must be followed by two zeros.  Since the final position of the bit string is determined, such a selection corresponds to the arrangement of $28$ objects, three blocks of the form $100$ and $25$ zeros.  We must choose which three of these $28$ positions are filled with a block of the form $100$, which can be done in $\binom{28}{3}$ ways.

*Case 2:*  The number $34$ is selected.

There must be a $1$ in the next to last position and a $0$ in the last position.  Since the final two positions of the bit string are determined, such a selection corresponds to the arrangement of $27$ objects, three blocks of the form $100$ and $24$ zeros.  We must choose which three of these $27$ positions can be filled with a block of the form $100$, which can be done in $\binom{27}{3}$ ways.

*Case 3:*  Neither $34$ nor $35$ is selected.

In this case, each selected number is followed by two numbers that are not selected.  Hence, a selection can be represented as an arrangement of $27$ objects, four blocks of the form $100$ and $23$ zeros.  We must select which four of these $27$ positions are filled with a block of the form $100$, which can be done in $\binom{27}{4}$ ways.

*Total:*  Since the three cases are mutually exclusive, the number of possible selections is 
$$\binom{28}{3} + \binom{27}{3} + \binom{27}{4} = \binom{28}{3} + \binom{28}{4} = \binom{29}{4}$$
where we have applied [Pascal's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_rule) twice.

Answer (score 4):

Representing unchosen numbers as black balls, and chosen ones as white balls,
with boxes in which black balls not shown can be filled to make a total of $35$ balls.

$\large\boxed.\circ\bullet\bullet\boxed.\circ\bullet\bullet\boxed.\circ\bullet\bullet\boxed.\circ\boxed.$

25 black balls need to be filled in $5$ boxes any which way.

Using [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29), we get $\binom{25+5-1}{5-1}$ sequences.

Number each such sequence from left to right to identify the chosen numbers in that sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A(n,k)$ be the number of ways to choose $k$ integers from $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ subject to the requirement that the differences are all $\ge 3$.  If you use $n$, then you can't use $n-1$ or $n-2$, and so
you need to choose $k-1$ integers in $\{1, \ldots, n-3\}$ with the same restriction on differences.  If you don't use $n$, then you need $k$ integers in $\{1, \ldots, n-1\}$.  Thus you get the recursion

$$ A(n,k) = A(n-3, k-1) + A(n-1,k)$$